# Accessing a Java web application via LAN

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications

I have a basic web application written in Java, running on a tomcat on my localhost. Currently it's just a simple application with a single servlet to which I access from my browser. On the localhost it is working perfectly, but when I try to access it from another machine via LAN, it doesn't return expected results.

My servlet code is

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fname=req.getParameter("fname");
        String lname=req.getParameter("lname");
        ServletOutputStream pw=resp.getOutputStream();
        pw.println("Hello"+" "+fname+" "+lname);
        pw.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy();
    }
}
```

My web.xml code is

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>n1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>demo.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>n1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myapp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My HTML form code is

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/app1/myapp" name="myform">
        <br />FirstName:<input type="text" name="fname" />
        <br />LastName:<input type="text" name="lname" />
        <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I access my HTML form from the browser using `http://localhost:8080/app1/htmls/a.html`

When I access the form from another machine using the same address, the browser displays the form, but after I click on the submit button, the browser returns as "web page not found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post action goes to localhost!
Try again with:

```
<form method="post" action="/app1/myapp" name="myform">
```